# How can I use lodash in dojo?

Tags: dojo, lodash

Is there a module for lodash that I can import into my dojo project? I know that I can always reference it by `window._`, but I wanted to be more conventional (as far as dojo is concerned) and formally require it into my module.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the AMD branch? https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/3.9.3-amd

You should then be able to add it to your packages, and require it in like any other module.

**Edit:** It worked locally by adding lodash to the packages to my dojoConfig object

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    baseUrl: '.',
    packages: [
        'app',
        'dgrid',
        'dijit',
        'dojo',
        'dojox',
        'put-selector',
        'xstyle',
        'lodash'
    ],
    selectorEngine: 'lite',
    tlmSiblingOfDojo: false
};
```

I was then able to use the lodash modules:

```
define(['lodash/array/union'], function (union) {
    var app = {};

    // Lodash example
    var employees = ['John', 'Sam', 'Bob'],
        employees2 = ['Jane', 'Kari', 'Jamie'];

    console.log(employees);
    console.log(employees2);
    console.log('=== Union Result ===');
    console.log(union(employees, employees2));

    return app;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I added the all the modules to my project. Then, I required in lodash/array but I am getting an error...

Comment: I was curious, so I tried it on my machine and it worked. I uploaded the project for you to clone and take a look:  `git clone --recursive https://github.com/kyledodge/dojo-lodash-example`  ...Once you clone the project, navigate to the src/index.html file and open the console. I'm using a basic lodash union on two arrays. Check the dojo config in src/index.html and where I use the module in src/main/app.js. This should help to narrow down where your issue is I hope. Sidenote: I was able to do this quickly by using the Dojo boilerplate as a template: https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate